# WordPress custom caching

Tags: wordpress

On the homepage of my website I have the 6 latest Youtube videos from a Youtube Channel, to get the video ID's I use the Youtube V3 API, but I only really need these videos to be updated every day +/-.

So I think the best approach is to store the ID's in WordPress database, look it up every page load. Check if it's been 24 hours since the ID's have been stored, if not I'll query the Youtube API and insert the new ID's, otherwise I'll just return the ID's from the database.

Is there a way to implement this using WordPress functions / tables, or do I have to create a custom table for something like this? :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement this custom. Create plugin for save multiple Youtube ID's in custom table.

Thanks

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That's bad to hear, I'm using a custom theme so I won't need to create a plugin but I was hoping to avoid creating a new table.

Comment: Yes, You will be use wp_post and wp_postmeta tables for complete your requirements.

I had only suggest new table if you want each and everything in different table.